segfault with no reason in sight while implementing a dsu in c (probably a silly mistake)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Parent {
    int node;
    int sum;
} Parent;

typedef struct DSU {
    Parent* parent;
    int* rank;
} DSU;

void create_dsu(DSU* dsu, int n, int* wts)
{
    dsu->parent = malloc(sizeof(Parent) * n);
    dsu->rank = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dsu->parent[i].sum = wts[i];
        dsu->parent[i].node = i;
        dsu->rank[i] = 0;
    }
}

int find_parent(DSU* dsu, int n)
{
    if (n == dsu->parent[n].node) {
        return n;
    }

    return dsu->parent[n].node = find_parent(dsu, n);
}

void union_by_rank(DSU* dsu, int u, int v)
{
    int up = find_parent(dsu, u);
    int vp = find_parent(dsu, v);
    if (up == vp) {
        return;
    }

    else if (dsu->rank[up] > dsu->rank[vp]) {
        dsu->parent[vp].node = up;
        dsu->parent[up].sum += dsu->parent[vp].sum;
    }

    else if (dsu->rank[vp] > dsu->rank[up]) {
        dsu->parent[up].node = vp;
        dsu->parent[vp].sum += dsu->parent[up].sum;
    }

    else {
        dsu->parent[up].node = vp;
        dsu->rank[vp]++;
        dsu->parent[vp].sum += dsu->parent[up].sum;
    }
}

int find_sum(DSU* dsu, int u)
{
    int up = find_parent(dsu, u); // causes a segfault
                                  //
    // printf("%d\n", dsu->parent[3].sum); -> 17
    // printf("%d\n", dsu->parent[0].sum); -> 11
    return (dsu->parent[up].sum);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 11, 13, 1, 3, 5 };
    DSU dsu;
    create_dsu(&dsu, 5, arr);

    union_by_rank(&dsu, 1, 3);
    union_by_rank(&dsu, 2, 3);
    union_by_rank(&dsu, 0, 4);
    //
    printf("%d\n", find_sum(&dsu, 2));
}

Here I am trying to implement a Disjoint Set Union in C.
In the program, there are 5 nodes which I connect using the union_by_rank function.
The function findSum aims to find the sum of the sets with input one of the nodes.
Example:
nodes have the value 11, 13, 1, 3, 5
if nodes 1-2-3 are connected and nodes 0-4 are connected
then the sum for node 2 will be 13 + 1 + 3 = 17 (summation of node 1, 2 and 3 weights)
For some reason the find_parent int findSum function segfaults when it works just fine in the union function. As I can print the values in the findSum using printf
find_parent should have worked as it does in union function

Start by using a debugger to catch the crash and see when and where in your code it happens. Examine all involved variables at the time and location of the crash, do they all look valid? And if that doesn't help, then try to minimize the code, to make it simpler, until the crash disappears (perhaps even to an empty main function). Then add one single statement at a time, until the crash happens, to help you locate it and what the reason might be.

Thanks for the prompt reply! I did check with gdb and the error occurs at find_parent in find_sum. Which is weird as the function works fine when called from union function

Your find_parent function calls itself. Are you sure you're not seeing stack overflow from this recursion?

When you catch the crash look at the call-stack. Does it seem to be endless calls to find_parent? Then you have a recursion issue as mentioned by @mathematician1975.

yes....it was the find_parent function  I was passing the same node to the recursive call when I should have passed it's parent. Ahhhh the amount of time spent debugging this silly mistake. Thanks!

Ok, so the logic for the find_parent was wrong. The find_parent should have been
int find_parent(DSU* dsu, int n)
{
    if (n == dsu->parent[n].node) {
        return n;
    }

    return dsu->parent[n].node = find_parent(dsu, dsu->parent[n].node);
}

